# quotient representation -- show that it actually is a linear representation

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $U \subset V$ be a $G$-invariant subspace and $\rho : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ a linear representation.

Show that $\rho_{U} : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V/U)$ with $\rho_U(g)(v+U) = \rho(g)(v) + U$ is a linear representation.

---

So I try to show that it is a homomorphism

$\rho_U(gh)(v+U) = \rho(gh)(v) + U = \rho(g) \circ \rho(h)(v) + U$

and want to get there: $\rho_U(g) \circ \rho_U(h)(v+U) \overset{?}{=} \rho(g)(v)+U \circ \rho(h)(v) +U$

Is it working like this? I feel uncomfortable in handling the v+U correctly..

Comment: Note that $\rho(g)(v)\circ\rho(h)(v)$ doesn't make sense -- what you actually want is $\rho(g)\circ\rho(h)(v)$, i.e. $\rho(g)\left(\rho(h)(v)\right)$.  Similarly the equation beginning with $\rho_U(g)(v+U)\circ\rho_U(h)(v+U)$ doesn't make sense.  Were those typos or is there some deeper misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you write things in the wrong way, because you "compose" things living in $V/U$. Instead, you should compose things living in $GL(V/U)$ and *then* evaluate that composition at some $v+U$. So, as you say,
$\rho_U(gh)$ sends $\overline v:=v+U$ to $(\rho(gh)(v))+U=(\rho g\circ\rho h)(v) + U$. On the other hand, 
$$
(\rho_Ug\circ\rho_Uh)(\overline v)=(\rho_Ug)((\rho h)(v)+U)=(\rho g)((\rho h)(v))+U=(\rho g\circ\rho h)(v) + U.
$$